# How to access Payload and MuleMessage in @Processor method

Tags: java, customization, mule, mule-studio

I have been working with implementing my custom processors using the Mule Devkit.

I have created the project with "mule-devkit-archetype-generic" archetype.
It has given me the class with annotations "@Module" and "@Processor"

I can pass a parameter to my processor method.

But I couldn't get a way to access MuleMessage and Payload inside my @Processor method.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the payload use:

```
@Payload final DESIRED_TYPE payload
```

replacing `DESIRED_TYPE` with the type you want and Mule will auto-transform the current payload to the desired type.

For example, this gives you a byte payload:

```
@Payload final byte[] payload
```

To access the MuleMessage, you actually access the MuleEvent and get the message from it. For this you need to add the `@Inject` annotation on your `@Processor` method and add a `MuleEvent muleEvent` argument to your processor method.

**UPDATE 2017/08/31 using Mule 3.8.1**

DevKit now generates a compile error if you try to annotate `@Processor` with `@Inject`.  The error message states that if you simply add a `MuleEvent` or `MuleMessage` parameter to your `@Processor` method, DevKit will properly inject the parameters.